# Taking screen shot of current OS X or iTerm terminal window

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables

In Linux, I'm using `imagemagick import -window $WINDOWID` to take a screencapture of the terminal.

Is there something similar in OS X?

Comment: Technically, `WINDOWID` is set by your X server, and is indeed available in (for example) an `xterm` running under XQuartz. At the very least, an answer will depend on what terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: Ideally, I'd want to support both iterm2 and the default terminal.

Comment: What is the script trying to do with the window ID? Quartz window IDs certainly exist but there's no easy way to get one from a terminal session and even then, I doubt it'd be useful to your bash script.

Comment: @NicholasRiley I'm using imagemagick `import -window $WINDOWID` to take a screencapture of the terminal.

Comment: OK, I answered your question now :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to be using `screencapture` rather than `import`, which only works on X11 windows.

If the window is in front, you can try:

```
screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to id of window 1') test.png
```

See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/) question for some more background.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `tty` command.

```
$ tty
/dev/ttys001
```

You can see what commands are running on that terminal by using `ps -t :

```
$ ps -t s001  #Where `tty` returns /dev/ttys001
```

You can also try `pgrep` too:

```
$ pgrep -t s001
```

---

## Edit (You can/I can)

Oh, this is for a screen capture... Wasn't in the OP.

`$WINDOWID` is a X11 thing, and so is `imagemagick`. Linux GUI (both KDE and Gnome) are based upon the X11 protocol. The Mac GUI isn't.

On Mac OS X, there's a `screencapture` command. I haven't used it, but let's look at the manpage:

> The screencapture utility is not very well documented to date.

You're on your own.

One more trick...

You can run the X11 server on the Mac. [The server is no longer included in Mountain Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293), but Apple recommends you to install it from the [XQuartz Project](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).

You can run the X11 server, then use XTerm windows which will have a Windows ID that can be used with `imagemagick`.

Comment: the first terminal name should be `ttys000`, it usually returns `No such file or directory` if there's a single terminal tab.

Comment: I opened a second tab and ran a process on there, so I could see it on the first tab. That's why I have `s001` and not `s000` My advise is to use the `tty` command to see your terminal ID, then you can use that to find your processes. I'll update my answer to make that more obvious.

Comment: How do you identify a GUI window given a tty?

Comment: The OP is asking about a "***bash script*** which needs to know the window id of ***the terminal*** that it's running in". That is a tty. Knowing that will help the BASH script identify itself because it can limit the processes displayed via `ps` or `pgrep` by the name of the tty.

Answer (score 0):

( Command + Control + Shift + 4 + Space ) for capturing a screenshot of the app window ..
Refer to this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361 for learning more about capturing screenshots in macOS..